# Undeploy IIS service and delete the Physical Service folder immediately - IIS Recycle

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

If I undeploy a service from IIS and delete the Physical Service folder immediately all the services installed in IIS are shutting down and starting again with the message Configuration changed.If I don't delete the physical folder immediately and wait some seconds this problem don't occurs. 
It happens only in Windows server 2012 with IIS 8.5, in Windows Server 2008 7.5 this problem doesn't occur.

Steps:

- Remove App

> appcmd delete app /app.name: string

- Delete AppPool

> appcmd delete apppool /apppool.name: string

- Delete service Physical folder

Environment:

- Windows server 2012
- IIS 8.5

Check the follow Event Viewer log (This happens to all IIS services installed):

[image: Configuration Changed - Event Viewer log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an IIS error of version 8.5. 
The optional hotfix [KB3052480](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3052480/unexpected-asp.net-application-shutdown-after-many-app-data-file-changes-occur-on-a-server-that-is-running-windows-server-2012-r2) solved this problem. 
The scenario described on hotfix page is not the same but the symptom is "In this scenario, you experience an unexpected ASP.NET application shutdown because of high disk I/O and configuration changes." 
If anyone had this problem, just install this hotfix.